# Is it possible HTML5 Metro Application consuming web services in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, html, microsoft-metro

I search through web and stackoverflow, but still couldn't get some tutorial for this.
i more familiar on how to create function in php to deal with database and using javascript to talk to the php like [host the php somewhere else with the database and call the function from windows 8 to deal with the database and consume data](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap). is it can be done through windows 8 ? or is there any limitation on this or any alternative way except WCF, RIA ?

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HTML Metro application is just the same as anything in the browser; it can make the same XHR calls with one advantage; you can overcome the same origin policy by declaring target hosts in the manifest.

Anything you would normally do with an XHR or similar will work here too.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. finally confirmed and now going to convert my xaml app into html. but may i get some tutorial on edit the origin policy, target host ? Thank you =)

Comment: You can just go into the editor for the manifest in vs, and add it in there; it should be super easy, and there's nothing you need to do on the back end.